# HTML file input not respecting overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, file-upload

I have a `file input` element inside of a `div` with a `border-radius` and `overflow` set to `hidden`, but for some reason I am able to activate the file input by clicking in the area the `border-radius` cuts off.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7consvgu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I have updated your code is JSFiddle - [https://jsfiddle.net/7consvgu/4/][1]
    * Changes: Input width added: 100%;
    * Border-radius: same as circle
    * Box-sizing: border-box for all elements for normalize
    * Padding: to align text horizontal & vertical center
```

Comment: what is this supposed to do? adding `width: 100%;` is redundant and does not fix the issue.

Comment: `border-radius:50%` is what seems to fix the issue.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Is this issue fixed? It doesn't seem fixed on jsFiddle. And what did you mean about `border-radius:50%`? This was in the css to begin with, no?

Comment: @RamTobolski it is fixed in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7consvgu/4/ - the `border-radius` had not been applied to the file input, only to the container circle.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Oh I see, thanks. The `box-sizing: border-box` is also involved. Krishna, nice trick. I simplied the example somewhat (removed the "circle" div, and redundant attributes) here: https://jsfiddle.net/ramtob/7consvgu/5/